# Is it possible to return Observable that emits array that is constructed by awaiting async methods?

Tags: angular, async-await, rxjs, angular2-observables

I have method below that builds but doesn't work:

```
  get screenShotResults$(): Observable<ScreenshotFile[]> { 
    return this.ngRedux.select<ICommunicationState>('communication').pipe(map(newState => {
      const ret: ScreenshotFile[] = [];
      newState.fileResults.forEach(async result => {
        if (result.type === 'SCREENSHOT') {
          const blob = await this.fileLocalStoreService.getAsync(result.id);
          if (blob !== undefined) {
            ret.push({id: result.id, blob: blob})
          }
        }
      });
      return ret;
    }));
  }
```

The idea is that it gets file from indexedDb. But as there's no synchronous API i'm struggling with the implementation.

The awaited method looks like this:

```
  public async getAsync(key: string) {
    let blob: IFileBlob | undefined;
    blob = await this.db.files.get(key);
    if (blob === undefined) {
      return undefined
    }
    return blob.file;
  }
```

it's using Dexie.

```
interface IFileBlob {
  id: string;
  file: Blob;
}
```

newState.fileResults is array of these:

```
export interface IFileResult {
  id: string;
  type: string;
}
```

So is anything like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try by converting the promise object (returned by async method) to observable using "fromPromise" method. Also, Use "forkJoin" to join all observable output into single obserable and finally, replace the "map" with "switchMap" to replace the stream with observable accumulated result. Below is representative code that may help you:

```
function getCount(): Observable<number> {
  return of(10);
}

// This is your "getAsync" method
async function getNumberPromise(value: number) {
  return value;
}

// This is your inner 'newState.fileResults.forEach' loop
function getNumberObservables(entries: number[]): Observable<number[]> {
  return forkJoin(entries.map((value, index) => {
    return from(getNumberPromise(index));
  }));
}

// this is your 'this.ngRedux.select<ICommunicationState>('communication').pipe(map(...'
function getAllFiles(): Observable<number[]> {
  return getCount().pipe(switchMap(count => {
    const entries = new Array(count);
    return getNumberObservables(entries);
  }));
}
```

Comment: @char m: is this useful?

Comment: thanks! i was thinking something like this, i need to check this properly.

Comment: Glad to hear this may be useful reference to you.

Comment: what is  getCount() in this example?

Comment: @char m Update code snippet with "getCount" method.